# linker command failed in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was building an app, but later on I quickly changed something(a value in char variable) and tried to load again, now I am getting this error

```
ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have undone what I have done, but still I am getting this error.
I have tried to delete build folder, it did not work... I also performed clean and build but still it cannot build...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the files included in the build. Quite possibly there are some duplicate implementation (or perhaps header?) files included.

1. Navigate to `{Project}` > `{Target}` > `Build Phases`.
2. Check the `Compile Sources` build phase for duplicates.
3. Remove all duplicate files.

Also make sure no duplicate libraries are included in the project. You may check this in the `Link Binary With Library` phase. Basically same story as above, but for libraries.

Finally make sure to clean the project before building (`Product` > `Clean`).

Answer (score 0):

My error message was a little different - duplicate symbols ... in *ClassImplmentationFile.*m

I didn't have any of the duplicates, as described above, but I noticed that the .m files that were listed in the error message, were in Build Phases/ Compile Sources.

I removed them from there and the thing ran fine.

I didn't put them in there.  I guess Xcode auto-screwed-up my project at some point.  : - )